# Help needed for integrating Displaytag with spring web mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, pagination, displaytag

I just wants to know that is it possible to integrate Displaytag with spring web mvc ?

If it is possible then can anybody please provide some tutorial or links for that ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick google for "DisplayTag Spring" suggests it works.

From [DisplayTag with Spring](http://bowerstudios.com/node/537)

> There is no extra configuration needed
>   to use the displayTag with Spring.
>   Just drop in the jar file to
>   WEB-INF/lib and start using it in your
>   jsps

From [How to use display tag library in Spring MVC](http://forums.devarticles.com/java-development-38/how-to-use-display-tag-library-in-spring-mvc-81936.html)

> Place these three jars under
>   WEB-INF/lib folder displaytag-1.2.jar,
>   displaytag-export-poi-1.2.jar and
>   displaytag-portlet-1.2.jar.
>
> Before using it in your jsp you should
>   have the below line <%@ taglib
>   uri="://displaytag.sf.net"
>   prefix="display"%>and now you can use
>   it how ever you want like
>
> note - prefix uri with http.

Btw. a common problem that occurs

> with Displaytag + Spring canned
>   *FormController is that onSubmit is (by default) only called on POST
>   requests. Keep in mind that displaytag
>   uses GET requests for sorting and
>   pagination (as it should), so you may
>   have to play with overriding the
>   isFormSubmission method in your
>   controller, if you want to handle
>   sorting and pagination in onSubmit